# How to use global post counter in the loop?

Tags: wp-query, count

In the Loop use this code

```
<?php $count = $wp_query->current_post;  echo $count; ?>
```

On first page post counts from 0 to 14, but from second page post counts from 0 to 14 to. How use global counter for count post on second from 15 to 29, third from 30 to 44 ...

Comment: You need to use `get_option( 'posts_per_page' )` and `get_query_var( 'paged' )` to calculate your post numbers

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thnx for answer, maybe you have little example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already stated in a comment,

> You need to use `get_option( 'posts_per_page' )` and `get_query_var( 'paged' )` to calculate your post numbers

You can do something like the following: (*I have commented the code to make it easy to follow. This goes into functions.php*)

```
function get_post_number()
{
    global $wp_query;

    /*
     * Get current page number. Set page 1 to one as get_query_var( 'paged' ) will be 0
     */
    $current_page_number   = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    /* 
     * Get the posts_per_page option that is set under "Reading"
     */
    $posts_per_page        = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
    /*
     * Get the current post position in the loop, add 1 because the counter starts at 0
     */
    $current_post_position = $wp_query->current_post + 1;

    /*
     * If this is page one, return the post position as is
     */
    if ( $current_page_number == 1 )
        return $current_post_position;

    /*
     * Calculate the post number on paged pages
     */
    return ( $posts_per_page * ( $current_page_number - 1 ) ) + $current_post_position;
}
```

You can then use it as follow in your templates to display the correct post numbers (*You need to use this **inside** the loop*)

```
echo get_post_number();
```

Comment: What would you use this for?

Comment: I think from the OP it is quite clear that this will display the current post post number :-)

Comment: @BradDalton I use this for Leaflet Map, to show post on map whit popup open. Can see here http://1871.by (but in russian)