# Display Count of posts

Tags: wp-query, categories, count

I'm trying to create a counter that will display the page number followed by the page count of a category page, where there is 1 post per page. For example if there are 10 posts in a category: `1/10`, `2/10`, etc. I was able to display the page number using the code supplied by @PieterGoosen ([How to use global post counter in the loop?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185529/how-to-use-global-post-counter-in-the-loo)) but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to display the page count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get that number from the same `$wp_query` object:

```
global $wp_query;
$num_pages = $wp_query->found_posts;
```

`$num_pages` will contain the total count that matches your category (or whatever other criteria you're using).

If you're just looking to get a string you can display, this modified version of the function will work.

```
function get_post_number()
{
    global $wp_query;

    /*
     * Get current page number. Set page 1 to one as get_query_var( 'paged' ) will be 0
     */
    $current_page_number   = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    /* 
     * Get the posts_per_page option that is set under "Reading"
     */
    $posts_per_page        = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
    /*
     * Get the current post position in the loop, add 1 because the counter starts at 0
     */
    $current_post_position = $wp_query->current_post + 1;

    /*
     * If this is page one, return the post position as is
     */
    if ( $current_page_number == 1 )
        return $current_post_position;

    /*
     * Calculate the post number on paged pages
     */
    return ( ( $posts_per_page * ( $current_page_number - 1 ) ) + $current_post_position ). '/' . $wp_query->found_posts;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my php is pretty sketchy. So I add that code to my function. How do I get $num_pages to display in my content.php? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the function from that post verbatim?

Comment: Yes. I didn't change anything except add the bit you have me.

Comment: I see where you're coming from. get_posts_number will have the entire thing I want to show. The part I'm not sure about is what to add to the result in the function.

Comment: I've edited the post with a modified version of the function that will return page/total as a string.

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly. I figured that's what you meant but I wasn't sure the right syntax.